# How to read multiple expressions from a file?

Tags: c++, file-io, eof

I have the following code

```
int main()
{
    Expression* expression;
    char paren, comma;
    string program;

    freopen("input", "r", stdin);

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter expression: ";
        cin >> paren;
        expression = SubExpression::parse();
        cin >> comma;  
        parseAssignments();
        cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << endl;
        if(cin.eof())
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void parseAssignments()
{
    char assignop, delimiter;
    string variable;
    int value;
    do
    {
        variable = parseName();
        cin >> ws >> assignop >> value >> delimiter;
        symbolTable.insert(variable, value);
    }
    while (delimiter == ',');
}
```

I want to read multiple expressions from a file using cin only. No matter where I put cin.eof() in the while loop, program reads input one more time and then crashes. I ahve also tried cin.peek() but still the same output. Suggest a ways to read EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed countless times before, `eof()` is **never** the right tool.

You want this:

```
Expression * expression = nullptr;

for (char paren, comma;
     std::cin >> paren                     &&
     (expression = SubExpression::parse()) &&
     std::cin >> comma                     &&
     parseAssignments();
    )
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << expression->evaluate() << "\n";
}
```

Here we assume that both `parse()` and `parseAssignments()` return something that's convertible to `true` on success and `false` on failure (like a  null pointer).

You might also want to insert checks that the delimiters are as expected, e.g. `paren == '('` and `comma == ','`.